# Does Ubuntu ever push new versions of GCC into the package repository between releases?

Tags: package-management, repository, synaptic, versions, gcc

Current version of GCC in Ubuntu 11.04 is 4.5.2. For certain C++0x features, I need GCC version 4.6, but would like to avoid compiling from source. Is there hope that Ubuntu will update GCC in the package repository before the next release in October (11.10).

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24523/will-gcc-be-upgraded-to-4-5-in-one-of-the-10-04-releases) asks a similar thing except for an earlier version of Ubuntu and GCC.

A second part of the question, if the answer is "no" to the first, then can I hope to see it appear in Ubuntu's unstable repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they will change the compiler version in a release, because *everything* is compiled with the version provided in the package repositories. A new major version of gcc would require a total recompilation and thus re-installation of every package to maintain compatibility.

By the way, compiling gcc from source is surprisingly easy, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that newer packages exist for GCC in a PPA or third party repository. But compiling from source is often the way to go if you want the very latest release.